# creating tiles with check selection in window phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, silverlight-toolkit

[image]

I want to create a series of tiles for a window phone 8 application some thing like this,
is there any control or toolkit which provides such feature...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this checked's tile exist on a library on Windows phone. I never found it!

Why don't create your own Customize Tile with a tile component and a checkbox component?

You create a tile and you associate a [chekbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.checkbox%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) at this tile.

Also, maybe you can help you with this sample of library for create customize Tiles or image with Checkbox: [Telerik with WrapMode for DataBound ListBox](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/databoundlistbox.aspx).

For create a Customize tile with the [Telerik RADControl library](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx), this is a sample:

```
<ScrollViewer Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutMenuRoot">
        <telerikPrimitives:RadHubTile 
            ImageSource="/Assets/TilesImage.png"
            Tap="MyFunction"
            Title="My Tile Title"
            IsFrozen="True"        // move with a tile background or not.
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            x:Name="MyTileName" 
            Height="168" 
            Margin="12,10,0,0" 
            Width="162">
        </telerikPrimitives:RadHubTile>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

But, This library isn't free...
I think other Open source library exist for create a tiles...

Also, You can create a full Tile by Yoursel (with the checkBox), with a basic Windows Phone components:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF77B608" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" Margin="10,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="69" Margin="10,69,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Label" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="201" SelectionForeground="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
        <CheckBox Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: thanks doc, but can you tell me how to create own tile with selection as shown above please share any resource if you have...

Comment: Hi! I've add sample for create a customize Tile with RadControl and for create a Tiles in your Application by Yourself with basic Controls :)